# How to link classes from JDK into scaladoc-generated doc?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scaladoc

I'm trying to link classes from the JDK into the scaladoc-generated doc.
I've used the `-doc-external-doc` option of scaladoc 2.10.1 but without success.

I'm using `-doc-external-doc:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar#http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/`, but I get links such as `index.html#java.io.File` instead of `index.html?java/io/File.html`.
Seems like this option only works for scaladoc-generated doc.

Did I miss an option in scaladoc or should I fill a feature request?

I've configured sbt as follows:

```
 scalacOptions in (Compile,doc) += "-doc-external-doc:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar#http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api"
```

Note: I've seen the `Opts.doc.externalAPI` util in the upcoming sbt 0.13. I think a nice addition (not sure if it's possible) would be to pass a `ModuleID` instead of a `File`. The util would figure out which file corresponds to the `ModuleID`.

Comment: You should report to scaladoc.

Comment: Is there a command line for this outside sbt? Following @jsuereth's answer, sbt just passes the options to scaladoc and if it doesn't support the feature, sbt doesn't either.

Answer (score 7):

I use sbt 0.13.5.

There's no out-of-the-box way to have the feature of having Javadoc links inside scaladoc. And  as my understanding goes, it's not sbt's fault, but the way scaladoc works. As [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260601/jsuereth) pointed out in his comment [You should report to scaladoc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934488/how-to-link-classes-from-jdk-into-scaladoc-generated-doc#comment35871444_16934488)

There's however a workaround I came up with - postprocess the `doc`-generated scaladoc so the Java URLs get replaced to form proper Javadoc links.

The file **scaladoc.sbt** should be placed inside a sbt project and whenever `doc` task gets executed, the postprocessing via `fixJavaLinksTask` task kicks in.

**NOTE** There are lots of hardcoded paths so use it with caution (*aka* do the polishing however you see fit).

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex.Match

autoAPIMappings := true

// builds -doc-external-doc
apiMappings += (
    file("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar") -> 
    url("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api")
)

lazy val fixJavaLinksTask = taskKey[Unit](
    "Fix Java links - replace #java.io.File with ?java/io/File.html"
)

fixJavaLinksTask := {
  println("Fixing Java links")
  val t = (target in (Compile, doc)).value
  (t ** "*.html").get.filter(hasJavadocApiLink).foreach { f => 
    println("fixing " + f)
    val newContent = javadocApiLink.replaceAllIn(IO.read(f), fixJavaLinks)
    IO.write(f, newContent)
  }
}

val fixJavaLinks: Match => String = m =>
    m.group(1) + "?" + m.group(2).replace(".", "/") + ".html"

val javadocApiLink = """\"(http://docs\.oracle\.com/javase/8/docs/api/index\.html)#([^"]*)\"""".r

def hasJavadocApiLink(f: File): Boolean = (javadocApiLink findFirstIn IO.read(f)).nonEmpty

fixJavaLinksTask <<= fixJavaLinksTask triggeredBy (doc in Compile)
```

Answer (score 6):

I took the answer by @jacek-laskowski and modified it so that it avoid hard-coded strings and could be used for any number of Java libraries, not just the standard one.

**Edit:** the location of `rt.jar` is now determined from the runtime using `sun.boot.class.path` and does not have to be hard coded.

The only thing you need to modify is the map, which I have called `externalJavadocMap` in the following:

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.util.matching.Regex.Match

val externalJavadocMap = Map(
  "owlapi" -> "http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4_0_2/index.html"
)

/*
 * The rt.jar file is located in the path stored in the sun.boot.class.path system property.
 * See the Oracle documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html.
 */
val rtJar: String = System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path").split(java.io.File.pathSeparator).collectFirst {
  case str: String if str.endsWith(java.io.File.separator + "rt.jar") => str
}.get // fail hard if not found

val javaApiUrl: String = "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html"

val allExternalJavadocLinks: Seq[String] = javaApiUrl +: externalJavadocMap.values.toSeq

def javadocLinkRegex(javadocURL: String): Regex = ("""\"(\Q""" + javadocURL + """\E)#([^"]*)\"""").r

def hasJavadocLink(f: File): Boolean = allExternalJavadocLinks exists {
  javadocURL: String => 
    (javadocLinkRegex(javadocURL) findFirstIn IO.read(f)).nonEmpty
}

val fixJavaLinks: Match => String = m =>
  m.group(1) + "?" + m.group(2).replace(".", "/") + ".html"

/* You can print the classpath with `show compile:fullClasspath` in the SBT REPL.
 * From that list you can find the name of the jar for the managed dependency.
 */
lazy val documentationSettings = Seq(
  apiMappings ++= {
    // Lookup the path to jar from the classpath
    val classpath = (fullClasspath in Compile).value
    def findJar(nameBeginsWith: String): File = {
      classpath.find { attributed: Attributed[File] => (attributed.data ** s"$nameBeginsWith*.jar").get.nonEmpty }.get.data // fail hard if not found
    }
    // Define external documentation paths
    (externalJavadocMap map {
      case (name, javadocURL) => findJar(name) -> url(javadocURL)
    }) + (file(rtJar) -> url(javaApiUrl))
  },
  // Override the task to fix the links to JavaDoc
  doc in Compile <<= (doc in Compile) map {
    target: File =>
      (target ** "*.html").get.filter(hasJavadocLink).foreach { f => 
        //println(s"Fixing $f.")
        val newContent: String = allExternalJavadocLinks.foldLeft(IO.read(f)) {
          case (oldContent: String, javadocURL: String) =>
            javadocLinkRegex(javadocURL).replaceAllIn(oldContent, fixJavaLinks)
        }
        IO.write(f, newContent)
      }
      target
  }
)
```

I am using SBT 0.13.8.

Comment: I tried adding your code to my SBT build file, but ScalaDoc still cannot seem to find JDK classes. I probably did something stupid – this should be added to build.sbt, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be added to `build.sbt`. What is the value of `System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path")`? You can check by typing `console` from the SBT REPL to drop into the Scala REPL. Are running on Windows or Linux or Mac? Do you get any warnings when running the `doc` task?

Comment: @Hawk Perhaps most importantly, did you add `documentationSettings` to your project's settings? For example, something like `lazy val myProject = (project in file("myProject")).settings(documentationSettings: _*)` in `build.sbt`.

Comment: @AndrewL Adding `documentationSettings` to the project settings fixes it; as I had expected, I was doing something tremendously wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Someone should pluginize this. <hint> <hint>

Comment: re "someone should pluginize this", maybe it should be part of https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/sbt-api-mappings — someone might open an issue there

Comment: Alas, as of _JDK_ 9+, `System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path")` returns `null`, due to _Java_'s modularization, so this approach will not work unless you're using _JDK_ 8.