# How to link Java API classes using apiMappings?

Tags: sbt, scaladoc

How do you link to Java classes in sbt using `apiMappings`? This is my code below which works for various dependencies, but I'm unclear how to link to Java standard library classes?

```
apiMappings ++= {
  def findManagedDependency(organization: String, name: String): Option[File] = {
    (for {
      entry <- (fullClasspath in Runtime).value ++ (fullClasspath in Test).value
      module <- entry.get(moduleID.key) if module.organization == organization && module.name.startsWith(name)
    } yield entry.data).headOption
  }
  val links = Seq(
    findManagedDependency("org.scala-lang", "scala-library").map(d => d -> url(s"http://www.scala-lang.org/api/$scalaVsn/")),
    findManagedDependency("com.typesafe.akka", "akka-actor").map(d => d -> url(s"http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/$akkaVersion/")),
    findManagedDependency("com.typesafe", "config").map(d => d -> url("http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/")),
    findManagedDependency("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-core").map(d => d -> url("http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.1/")),
    findManagedDependency("io.spray", "spray-http").map(d => d -> url("http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/")),
    findManagedDependency("io.spray", "spray-routing").map(d => d -> url("http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/")),
    findManagedDependency("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api").map(d => d -> url("http://www.slf4j.org/api/")),
    findManagedDependency("com.typesafe.akka", "akka-testkit").map(d => d -> url(s"http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/$akkaVersion/")),
    findManagedDependency("org.specs2", "specs2").map(d => d -> url(s"http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-$specs2Version/"))
  )
  links.collect { case Some(d) => d }.toMap
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to link Java libraries or Scala standard library? If it's Java, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934488, and basically not supported by Scaladoc.

Comment: @EugeneYokota I'm trying to link to the standard Java library. Prior to 2.11 I used "-external-urls" and it worked great, but that option isn't available anymore. There's no legitimate way to do this anymore? That seems...not optimal.

Comment: What is missing in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/16934488/1305344 that you need for your use case? Can you do `last doc` after executing `doc` to see what options are missing and compare with the different versions of Scala? I really need more input to work on the use case.

Comment: Noting you're using what can roughly be called the “findManagedDependency pattern,” you might be interested [in an answer I've given to a related question that makes these mappings more generic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35673212/700420) (and reusable).

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution from [How to link classes from JDK into scaladoc-generated doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934488/how-to-link-classes-from-jdk-into-scaladoc-generated-doc), i.e. add the following to `apiMappings`:

```
apiMappings += (
    file("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar") -> 
    url("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api")
)
```

and `fixJavaLinksTask` task will do the rest with the following in `build.sbt`:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex.Match

autoAPIMappings := true

// builds -doc-external-doc
apiMappings += (
    file("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar") -> 
    url("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api")
)

lazy val fixJavaLinksTask = taskKey[Unit](
    "Fix Java links - replace #java.io.File with ?java/io/File.html"
)

fixJavaLinksTask := {
  println("Fixing Java links")
  val t = (target in (Compile, doc)).value
  (t ** "*.html").get.filter(hasJavadocApiLink).foreach { f => 
    println("fixing " + f)
    val newContent = javadocApiLink.replaceAllIn(IO.read(f), fixJavaLinks)
    IO.write(f, newContent)
  }
}

val fixJavaLinks: Match => String = m =>
    m.group(1) + "?" + m.group(2).replace(".", "/") + ".html"

val javadocApiLink = """\"(http://docs\.oracle\.com/javase/8/docs/api/index\.html)#([^"]*)\"""".r

def hasJavadocApiLink(f: File): Boolean = (javadocApiLink findFirstIn IO.read(f)).nonEmpty

fixJavaLinksTask <<= fixJavaLinksTask triggeredBy (doc in Compile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322970/1399246) what you are looking for.

This main difference between that answer and the other answer posted here is that the location of `rt.jar` is determined from the runtime, and not hard coded.